# Is there a closed formula for the joint of $X$ and $X^2$?

Tags: distributions, joint-distribution

I am working on a proof that requires the distribution of certain function of $X$ and $X^2$. Say that I have the density of $X\sim f_X(x)$. Can I use this information to answer how are $X$ and $X^2$ jointly distributed?

It seems straightforward that these variables are not independent and I don't see how I can find a method that allows me to answer this specific information.

Comment: The question is a little vague at present. They certainly won't be independent in general (of course); if $X$ is a continuous r.v., the bivariate distribution of $X,X^2$ will lie on a curve. You may want to consider $X<0$ separately from $X\geq 0$. Can you say what the situtation is you're dealing with? Is it just univariate as it seems there, or are you dealing with a function of a number of variables?

Comment: Since X² is a deterministic function of X, your joint distribution will be supported by the manifold $\{(x,y);\ y=x^2\}$. If you want to define a joint density fo (X,X²), you first need to define a measure on that curve. If you simply need a distribution, a Dirac mass for the conditional of X² given X will do.

Comment: Right, I forgot to add. I know that $X$ is a non-negative random variable. Now I think this makes a little bit of sense because you can get $X^2$ by observing $X$ and viceversa. So, can I say that the joint is a function of the marginals? Something like $f_{X,X^2}(x,y) = f_X(\min(x,\sqrt{y}))$ if $x,y\geq0$ sounds plausible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some discussion of a simple case; $X>0$ and continuous.

Let $Y=X^2$

$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x, Y\leq y) = P(X\leq \min(x,\sqrt y))=F_X(\min(x,\sqrt y))$

Of course, if $y=x^2$, that's just $F_X(x)$.

Here's a plot of a sample density for a particular $f_X$ (seen from "above", so the relationship between variables is clear; the density is indicated by how greyed in the curve is). The yellow and blue dots should make clear why "min" appears in the cdf - in each case we can see that the proportion of the density to the left and below the point is given by $F_X(\min(x,\sqrt y))$

[image]

If $X$ can be negative, you're best off dealing with the $X<0$ case separately as I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I actually do not understand the point of those two points since the distribution is concentrated on the curve $y=x^2$.

Comment: @Xi'an as it says, they're simply there to illustrate why "min" occurs in the cdf when the distribution is concentrated on a curve like that. Some people won't need to see more than the algebra; for others it won't be obvious until they see a picture. It's not anything very important, nor particularly necessary.